# ARIMAX with spark-timeseries

Tags: time-series, apache-spark

Cloudera recently added the [spark-time series library to github](https://github.com/cloudera/spark-timeseries). According to the [user docs](http://cloudera.github.io/spark-timeseries/0.2.0/scaladocs/index.html#com.cloudera.sparkts.models.ARIMA$), it definitely can fit autoregressive integrated moving average ([ARIMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_integrated_moving_average)) models, but I see no mention of ARIMAX, which takes into account explanatory variables. Does anyone with more experience with this library know whether ARIMAX is possible in the library's current implementation? Mathematically, I understand the difference between ARIMA and ARIMAX, and I know extending it myself wouldn't be terribly difficult, but I'm right now looking for an off-the-shelf solution in spark. Can anyone recommend an alternative spark implementation?

Answer (score 1):

Blast. It looks as though ARIMAX is [currently a work in progress](https://github.com/cloudera/spark-timeseries/issues/85) for the cloudera/spark-timeseries community. Although [some work has been done](https://github.com/cloudera/spark-timeseries/pull/51) on the model development side, it doesn't appear to have been merged in.